# Jenkins build job does not continue with downstream job after reboot of Slave machine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use a Master-Slave configuration with 2 slave machines (VMs). I have a Build job which simply reboots the slave machine using an 'Execute Windows batch command'

`shutdown.exe /r /t 00`

In Post-build Action I build another project (a downstream task) which installs a program and then executes it. However, my job fails instantly at reboot and ignores the downstream task. It works on one VM and not the other even though one machine is cloned from the other. It's driving me mad, any ideas?

This is the error I get in the Console Output:

```
Building remotely on TESTVM_1 in workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\Execute TestApp

[Execute TestApp] $ cmd /c call C:\QATEMP~1\hudson5086584301890012619.bat

C:\Jenkins\workspace\Execute TestApp>shutdown.exe /r /t 00 

C:\Jenkins\workspace\Execute TestApp>exit 0 
FATAL: java.io.IOException: Connection aborted: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport@2ae04688[name=TESTVM_1]
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Connection aborted: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport@2ae04688[name=TESTVM_1]
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:303)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:863)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.terminate(Channel.java:509)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport$1.terminate(AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$NioTransport.abort(NioChannelHub.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:629)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to TESTVM_1(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1433)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:796)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:953)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:540)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection aborted: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport@2ae04688[name=TESTVM_1]
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$NioTransport.abort(NioChannelHub.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:629)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer$Pointer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:137)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:310)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:561)
    ... 6 more
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using reboots immediately.  This means that the post-build steps such as archiving results are still running while the machine is rebooting.  Instead of /t 00, use /t 30, then take steps to ensure that no new jobs start running in those 30 seconds.  You may also want to add exit 0 after the shutdown command to ensure that the current batch command exists cleanly. The installation that you have in a post-build task should also go into another job.